# micrometer tracing using otel collector and jaeger

Tags: spring-boot, jaeger, micrometer-tracing

I am trying to set up micrometer tracing with Jaeger. I am able to see spans and event flow from the rest API to the web service, but not able to see logs in Jaeger spans, such as info logs that can be used in debugging.

so the question is if we can see slf4j logs in Jaeger with Micrometer tracing. Is this feature supported in Micrometer and if so how is it done?